# scala -- syntax to indicate any kind of anonymous function, whatsoever

Tags: scala, syntax, callback, anonymous-function

I'd like to be able to pass in callback functions as parameters to a method.  Right now, I can pass in a function of signature `() => Unit`, as in

```
def doSomething(fn:() => Unit) {
  //... do something
  fn()
}
```

which is fine, I suppose, but I'd like to be able to pass in any function with any parameters and any return type.

Is there a syntax to do that?

Thanks

Comment: How would you call it if you don't know beforehand what type and number of parameters it takes? How would you use the return value?

Comment: Would `def doSomething[A](fn:() => A) { ...` be enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to execute a function passed as a callback you have to be able to call it with the arguments it requires. `f: A => R` must be called as `f(someA)`, and `g: (A,B) => R` must be called as `f(someA, someB)`.

Implementing a callback you want a function that accepts a context and returns something (you don't care what the something is). For example `foreach` in scala.Option is defined as:

```
def foreach[U](f: (A) => U): Unit
```

The function is called with a value of type A but the result is discarded so we don't care what type it has. Alternatively if you don't care what was completed the callback function could be implemented as:

```
def onComplete[U](f: () => U): Unit
```

It would then allow being called with any function that takes no arguments:

```
val f: () => Int = ...
val g: () => String = ...

onComplete(f) // In result is discarded
onComplete(g) // String result is discarded
```

If you really wanted a function that accepted any possible function there are some tricks you could use (but you really shouldn't). For example you could define a view bound with implicit conversions:

```
// Type F is any type that can be converted to () => U
def onComplete[F <% () => U, U](f: F): Unit

// Define conversions for each Function type to Function0
implicit def f1tof0[A,U](f: A => U): () => U = ...
implicit def f2tof0[A,B,U](f: (A,B) => U): () => U = ...
implicit def f3tof0[A,B,C,U](f: (A,B,C) => U): () => U = ...
.
.
etc.
```

Now onComplete accepts any function:

```
val f: Int => String = ...
val g: (List[Int], String) => String = ...

onComplete(f)
onComplete(g)
```

Defining the types for the above conversions is relatively simple, but there is no rational way to implement them so is pretty much entirely useless.

Comment: That's not a context bound, it's a view bound (and it's also deprecated). You can replace it with `(implicit ev: F => () => U)`

Comment: Fixed the mistaken reference to a context bound. Thanks @GabrielePetronella